# Expectation and variance of the squared distance between $X$ and $Y$

Tags: statistics, euclidean-geometry, expected-value, uniform-distribution

Given that $X$ and $Y$ are two independent univariate random variables sampled uniformly from the unit interval [0,1]. I am trying to find the expected value and the variance of the random variable $Z = \mid X - Y  \mid ^2 $ (the squared distance between $X$ and $Y$.

So far, I'm assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are uniformly distributed and this is what I have: 
\begin{align}
Z &= \mid X - Y\mid ^2  \\
Z &= \mid X^2 - 2XY + Y^2 \mid \\
E[Z] &= \mid E[X^2] - 2E[XY] + E[Y^2]\mid \\
&= \mid E[X^2] - 2E[X]E[Y] + E[Y^2]\mid \\
&= \frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{b-a}(b^3-a^3)-2(\frac{a+b}{2})(\frac{a+b}{2})+\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{b-a}(b^3-a^3)
\end{align}

But I am not sure if this is the right approach or the right direction and what is E[Z] = $\mid X - Y\mid ^2$. If so, can I do something similar to the variance?

Comment: What you have done is correct but there are unnecessary absolute value signs: $|x-y|^{2}=x^{2}-2xy+y^{2}$ and there is no need for absolute value sign on the right side.

Comment: What is a and b?

Comment: that would be 0 and 1

Comment: Cross-posted at https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/447459/119261.

Comment: do I need to substitute 0 and 1 for a and b? @KaviRamaMurthy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I substitute 0 and 1 for a and b respectively to:

\begin{align}
&= \frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{b-a}(b^3-a^3)-2(\frac{a+b}{2})(\frac{a+b}{2})+\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{b-a}(b^3-a^3) \\
&=\frac{1}{6}
\end{align}

Would the answer (the expected value of Z) be $\frac{1}{6}$?

Comment: Yeah it's correct

Answer (score 1):

Variace is $E[(X-Y)^4] -[E[(X-Y)^2]]^2$

---

=$ E(X^4) + E(Y^4) + 6E(X^2)E(Y^2) -4E(X^3)E(Y) - 4E(X)E(Y^3) -\frac{1}{36}$

---

= $\frac{2}{5} + \frac{6}{9} - 1 - \frac{1}{36}$

---

=$\frac{7}{180}$

Comment: where is the $\frac{1}{36}$ from

Comment: E((X-Y)²)=$\frac{1}{6}$

Comment: do you mind helping with the next step of this problem? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3532371/find-the-variance-of-r-where-r-z-1-dotsb-z-d-and-z-i-x-i-y-i?noredirect=1#comment7264970_3532371