# Find the variance of $R$ where $R$ = $Z_1 + \dotsb + Z_d$ and $Z_i = |X_i - Y_i|^2$

Tags: statistics, expected-value, uniform-distribution, variance

So I am trying to find the Variance $R$ where $R$ = $Z_1 + \dotsb + Z_d$ and $Z_i = |X_i - Y_i|^2$

$X$ and $Y$ are d-dimensional points from a d-dimensional unit cube with a uniform distribution: $X,Y \in [0,1]^d$ which we can view this as drawing random
variables $X_1, . . . , X_d$ and $Y_1, . . . , Y_d$ independently and uniformly from $[0, 1]$

Assuming that this is correct:
\begin{align*}
R &= Z_1 + \dotsb+ Z_d\\
&= d  \cdot Z \\
R^2 &= d^2 \cdot Z^2\\
E[R^2] &= d^2 \cdot E[Z^2]\\
&=\frac{12d^2}{180}\\
&=\frac{d^2}{15}
\end{align*}
and with the information from: 
[Expectation and variance of the squared distance between $X$ and $Y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3531244/expectation-and-variance-of-the-squared-distance-between-x-and-y)

I was able to get to:
\begin{align*}
Var(R) &= E[R^2]-(E[R])^2\\
&=\frac{d^2}{15}-\frac{d^2}{36}
\end{align*}

Is this even correct? Or did I make a mistake along the way

Comment: I have doubts about what you mean by $R=d\cdot Z$ and $R^2=d^2\cdot Z^2$, and I think the $d^2$ in $E[R^2]=d^2\cdot E[Z^2]$ is wrong and should be $d$

Comment: doesn't squaring both sides of $R=d\cdot Z$ give $R^2=d^2\cdot Z^2$?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by $R=d\cdot Z$.   Are you saying $Z=Z_1=Z_2=\cdots=Z_d$? They cannot vary? That would mean points must be on one small part of your hypercube

Comment: I guess I'm wrong, $Z$ is the squared distance between the two random variable $X$ and $Y$ so the $Z$s can't all the be same. How can I go about this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$R^2 = \sum_{r=1}^d Z_r^2\  +\ $

$ \sum_{r=1}^d \sum_{r\not=s=1}^d Z_rZ_s$

---

$Z_r Z_s$ occurs d(d-1)times and $Z_r^2$ occur d times

---

$E(R^2)=  d\times E(Z^2)\ +\ d(d-1)\times [E(Z)]^2$ $=\frac{d}{15}\ +\frac{d(d-1)}{36}$

---

Variance = $ E(R^2) - [E(R)]^2=\frac{d}{15}\ +\ \frac{d(d-1)}{36}\  -\ \frac{d^2}{36} = \frac{7d}{180}$